# Minimum cost to visit museum

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I recently went for an hiring challenge and saw this question :

Given map of `N` museums with given entry fees and `M` weighted bidirectional roads connecting them. Starting from each museum, we need to find minimum cost to visit at least one museum. **The cost will be an addition of sum of weights of roads travelled and visited museum entry fee.**

Input format :

```
Number of museums N and number of roads M
Entry fees of each museum
Next M lines will have x, y, z where museum x and museum y are connected by road with weight z
```

Output Format :

```
N integers where ith integer denotes minimum cost to reach and enter any museum starting from ith museum.
```

Input :

```
5 4 
1 2 3 1 5
1 2 1
2 3 1
3 4 1
4 5 1
```

Output :

```
1 2 2 1 2
```

Here, starting from museum 1, we can directly visit museum 1 with entry fee of 1.
Starting from museum 3, we can visit museum 4 with cost of 2.

I need optimized approach efficient than applying dijsktra from each node of graph. Constraints are high enogh to avoid floyd warshall algorithm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ... so, did you try anything yet? :)

Comment: I have tried applying dijsktra from each node that time as specified, but, of course, it was beyond execution time limit.

Comment: How far did you run Dijkstra? Most of the time, you can stop early. Let's assume that you have a current solution with cost `c` (a museum that you already found), your current node has a road weight of `r` and the minimum museum fee that you have not visited yet is `m`. Then you can stop if `r + m >= c` as you cannot get to a better solution. Keep the museums in a tree structure where you can dynamically add and remove items and get the minimum fast (similar to the min filter in image processing).

Comment: I don't think we can stop early in dijsktra in this problem. I was finding shortest distance d[i] from a node to every other node and considering cost to enter that museum to be d[i]+e[i], I was finding minimum of this quantity.

Comment: Why do you think the strategy I showed would not work? You can even see it from the example output. They all have a cost of at most 2. There is no need to find the shortest path to the museum with 5 entry fee if you already have such a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your graph starts off with nodes of "outside Museum X" and edges roads between them.

You need a priority queue of entries that look like this:

```
{
    cost: xxx,
    outside_museum: xxx
}
```

You initialize it with entries that look like this:

```
{
    cost: entry_fee_for_museum_x,
    outside_museum: x
}
```

Keep a dictionary mapping museum to lowest cost named something like `cost_to_museum`.

And now your loop looks like this:

```
while queue not empty:
    get lowest cost item from queue
    if it's museum is not in cost_to_museum:
        cost_to_museum[item.outside_museum] = item.cost
        for each road connecting to museum:
            add to queue an entry for traveling to here from there
            (That is, location is the other museum, cost is road + current cost)
```

This should execute in time `O((n+m) log(n+m))` where `n` is the number of museums and `m` is the number of roads.

Comment: Can I say that you are modifying dijsktra to apply to this problem ? So, what are your suggestions to find this efficiently for each node

Comment: @PratikKale The correct usage of the priority queue **IS** the suggestion.  The number of entries in the queue max are `n+2m`, each of which takes `O(log(n+2m))` to insert and retrieve.  That slightly superlinear time is comparable to the time to read the file.

Comment: @NicoSchertler It is an answer to the question.  `cost_to_museum[from_museum]` is the cost of the cheapest path to a museum while standing outside of a museum.

Comment: Ah, I see. `cost_to_museum[i]` is the cost to visit any museum starting at `i`. I thought it would be the cost to visit museum `i`. Hence my confusion.